# how to get the uploaded file path using html , javascript , php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am uploading am image from my drive, it is uploaded successfully but I am unable to get the folder path of that image

for example:

E:\Allied logo\Allied Logo images

```
$('#pngfile').change(function (e) {
var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
console.log(this.files,tmppath);
        })
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here. The code you have isn't uploading anything … and if you were uploading something that any URL or path on the server would be determined by the server, not the client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

It'll give you a temporary path not the accurate path, you can use this script if you want to show selected image.

Here is the code :-

**HTML:-**

```
<input type="file" id="i_file" value=""> 
<input type="button" id="i_submit" value="Submit">
<br>
<img src="" width="200" style="display:none;" />
<br>
<div id="disp_tmp_path"></div>
```

**JS:**-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#i_file').change( function(event) {
        var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        $("img").fadeIn("fast").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
    
        $("#disp_tmp_path").html("Temporary Path(Copy it and try pasting it in browser address bar) --> <strong>["+tmppath+"]</strong>");
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function(){
    
            $('#fiad').change( function(event) {
                                                    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                                                    $("img").fadeIn("fast").attr('src',tmppath);
                
            });
  });  
  </script>
```

**Html**

```
<input type="file" id="fiad"><br><br>

<img src="" width="200" style="display:none;" />
```

you get file path inside `tmppath` here.